# Como puedo pasar parametros entre pantallas en React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Mis hablidades con React Native son muy basicas, y lo que quiero obtener es los posts segun cada categoria.

**Pantalla de Categorias**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { NavigationActions, DrawerNavigator,  StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import{Dimensions, Button, View, SafeAreaView, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default class WGoals extends Component {
static navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Categories'
    };

navigateToScreen = (route, params) => () => {
const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
  routeName: route,
  params: params
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
}

constructor(props)
  {
super(props);
this.state = { 
isLoading: true,
  }
}

  render() {

    return (

<Container style={styles.background_general}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.navigateToScreen('PostsScreen', itemId = '1')} >
                <Text>Category 1</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.navigateToScreen('PostsScreen', itemId = '2')} >
                <Text>Category 2</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
</Container>      
    );
  }
}
```

**Pantalla de Posts**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { NavigationActions, DrawerNavigator,  StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import{Dimensions, View, SafeAreaView, FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

export default class Posts extends Component {
static navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Posts'
};

  render() {

    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
    const itemId = params ? params.itemId : null;

    return (

<Container style={styles.background_general}>

<Text>Details Screen</Text>
<Text>itemId: {JSON.stringify(itemId)}</Text>

</Container>

    );
  }
    }
```

Comment: Una solución a largo plazo puede ser la implementacion de Redux en tu aplicación https://medium.com/@debian789/implementaci%C3%B3n-de-redux-en-react-native-6324e2a8c4aa

Comment: Muchachos! Primero la brújula. Creo que es un tema delicado ya que fue cambiando mucho a lo largo de las distintas versiones de Navigation. Y acá hay un **dato básico** que esta faltando... ¿Que versión de Navigation es la que esta instalada en tu entorno? Creo que sin ese dato no se puede hablar, porque es entrar ya en un terreno se suposiciones.
Lo mejor es leer la docu que de la versión de Navigation que corresponde con tu proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

Debes pasar un objeto con los parametros en el evento navigate() y recogerlo en la vista destino, quedaría así:

Desde tu vista **WGoals** llamas a navigate:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Posts", { misPosts: arrayConPosts });
```

y en tu vista **Posts** los coges de la siguiente forma:

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.misPosts
```

Lo ideal es recoger los datos del parámetro en **componentDidMount()** y alojarlo en tu state, quedaría de la siguiente manera:

//crea tu constructor

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    this.state = {
     misPosts: []
   };
}
```

//guarda tus posts cuando la vista se haya cargado

```
componentDidMount()
{
  this.setState({misPosts: this.props.navigation.navigate("Posts", {misPosts: arrayConPosts })
}
```

y por último en tu **render()**, muestra los posts en un List:

```
render(
  const misPosts = this.state.misPosts;

  return(
      <List dataArray={misPosts}
        renderRow={(item) =>
          <ListItem>
            <Text>{item.textoPost}</Text>
          </ListItem>
        }>
      </List>
   )
)
```

Espero que te sirva, ya nos cuentas¡